# Existence of group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Does there exist a noncyclic group which order is countable and it is isomorphic to every proper subgroup? If no, why? The answer seems to be no, but I can't prove it.

Comment: Consider the subgroup generated by some non-trivial element.

Comment: @verretа but I want it to be isomorphic to every proper subgroup.

Comment: Such a group does not exist, and I gave you a hint why.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Show that if it's true, the group is isomorphic to the cyclic group and hence contradicts the assumption.  Every group has a cyclic subgroup just take a non trivial element $r$ and look at $\langle r \rangle$.

Comment: I wasn't saying that it's infinite cyclic. But it's true that the proof isn't fully rigorous.

Comment: @Qudit The group is cyclic, because by assumption it is isomorphic to a cyclic group. Since it is countably infinite, it is infinite cyclic. The proof *is* fully rigorous.

Answer (score 0):

No nontrivial group $G$ can be isomorphic to its trivial subgroup.

More generally, take any element $g$ and consider the subgroup $\langle g \rangle$.
This is cyclic, so it is a proper subgroup of $G$ and not isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: A reasonable follow-up would be whether there's a $G$ isomorphic to all its non-cyclic subgroups.